# Executing a maven lifecycle target on artefact installed in local repo

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Is it possible to execute a lifecycle target (e.g. `integration-test`) on an artefact that has been *installed* within the local repo?

My use case is as follows.  I have a multi module project with many modules that dedicated various types of integration testing (compliance test, performance tests, etc).  I need to invoke these integration multiple times with different environment configurations.  These configurations are expressed as maven profiles and parameterised using properties.   I want to avoid recompiling the project over and over again.

I would like to have one build CI job performing the mvn install, then separate CI jobs performing the integration tests, triggered once the build CI job has passed.   The integration tests would simply invoke integration-test lifecycle phase of the installed artefact setting the profile and passing the parameters

I have tried pointing mvn at the .pom file *within* the local repo but this does not work.  It fails because it cannot find classes within the artefact's own JAR file (as if it were not being put on the classpath) - a problem that doesn't occur if I have my integration job checkout the tree and invoke the pom.xml within the source tree.

```
mvn -f ~/.m2/repo/x/y/z/myproj-perftests-x.x.x-SNAPSHOT.pom integration-test -Pmyprofile -Dparam1=blah
```

Comment: You can try to run depending on which plugin you use for running integration test (for example maven-failsafe-plugin) ...using the following: `failsafe:integration-test` ...? This will not run the whole life cycle....

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Maven plugins (normally) only work with project sources.

If your only concern is recompiling project again and again, consider splitting your project into the core part and the integration tests part. Then when running integration tests you'll only need to recompile the integration tests part.